# Prevent writing any changes to bootable USB

Tags: 16.04, boot, server, usb

I'm creating a reusable Ubuntu Server 16.04 image. The idea is that it would boot up from a USB drive, provide some services for a while, and then shut down.

Unfortunately, if a user removes the drive it's very likely to become corrupted.

I don't have a swap partition (it's awful for USB anyways) but is there another step I could take to prevent any persistent writes? Ideally you would reboot and the drive would be back to its original state, kind of like the live USB but with all my stuff on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was to mark the partition as read-only in `/etc/fstab`.

I changed the line for the root partition, `/`, from this:

```
UUID=949e37ad-bc64-47bd-8478-fa6661267d9f /           ext4    errors=remount-ro        0       1
```

To:

```
UUID=949e37ad-bc64-47bd-8478-fa6661267d9f /           ext4    ro,errors=remount-ro        0       1
```

Note the `ro,` before the `errors` bit.

You can see more on the [Fstab wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

This is also nice because once the system is booted you can also remount it as read-write if necessary.

```bsh
rootMount=$(findmnt / -o source -n)
mount -o remount,rw "${rootMount}" /
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want using a modified **Guest User account**

Guest User Accounts for 16.04 and prior, are controlled by lightdm.conf, so a minimal graphical interface is required:

```
sudo apt install xorg
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lightdm
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends openbox
```

Once logged in as guest Ctrl-Alt-F2 takes you to text mode.

If Guest Session is not already enabled, open /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and change:

```
allow-guest=true
```

Now there will be a Guest account.

**Modifying the Guest Account**

You may use an existing User Account, or create a new User Account, to use as a Live basis for customizing the Guest Session.

Make a directory for guest session, if one does not already exist:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/guest-session
```

Create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /home/{NAME} /etc/guest-session/skel
```

Where {NAME} is the name of the User Account you wish to use as a basis.

Any changes made to the user account will appear in the guest account.

Any changes to the guest account will be deleted at end of the session.

Comment: Is this a feature of the UI framework? I'm working with Ubuntu Server and booting to a command line.

Comment: @N Jones : lightdm installed to server 16.04 OK for me, When booting it gave an option for a Guest Session, however it fails to start session. I think it is trying to start a graphical session. Don't know if it can start a command line session instead. I think we would need a graphical interface for server to make this method work.

Comment: @N Jones : Maybe the best we can do is install a minimal GUI ie xorg+lightdm+openbox. Guest sessions worked OK for me with that.